# Unable to cast exceptions thrown via `throwTo` using `fromException`

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception

While working on a Haskell project I encounter the problem, that any exception thrown to a thread via `throwTo` results in a `Nothing` when casted from the `SomeException` type back into my own exception type using `fromException`. As a demonstration, consider this code snippet:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import           Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import           UnliftIO.Async     (async, asyncThreadId, waitCatch)
import           UnliftIO.Exception (Exception, SomeAsyncException (..), SomeException (..),
                                     asyncExceptionToException, catch, fromException, throwIO,
                                     throwTo, toException)

data MyException = Type1 | Type2
    deriving (Show)

instance Exception MyException

toMyException :: SomeException -> Maybe MyException
toMyException = fromException

sleepAndThrow :: (Exception e) => Int -> e -> IO ()
sleepAndThrow i e = do
    threadDelay (i * 1000000)
    print e
    throwIO e

main :: IO ()
main = do
    t1 <- async $ sleepAndThrow 1 Type1 -- Throw Type1 in 1 second
    t2 <- async $ threadDelay 500000 >> throwTo (asyncThreadId t1) Type2 -- Cancel t1 in 0.5
                                                                          -- seconds with Type2
    waitCatch t1 >>= \case
        Left e   -> putStr "Exception: " >> print (toMyException e)
        Right () -> error "this should not happen"
```

Looking at this, I would expect the following console output:

```
Exception: Just Type2
```

Whereas I get a:

```
Exception: Nothing
```

Can anyone of you please show me, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you replace `print (toMyException e)` with `print e`? What do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your exception an async exception if you're going to throw it asynchronously.

```
instance Exception MyException where
    toException = asyncExceptionToException
    fromException = asyncExceptionFromException
```

This means that you need to have two distinct types for `Type1` and `Type2` if you're going to throw `Type1` synchronously and `Type2` asynchronously.

But in general, I'd recommend not to use asynchronous exceptions directly, but use utilities in `async` package such as [`race`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race).